# Consulta basica de C#

Tags: c#, basic

Es un contador de números , si uno ingresa `OK` debería salir y mostrar la suma de los números ingresados. 
El contador funciona bien pero cuando ingreso `OK` en ves de salir del *while* la aplicación crashea.

```
static void Main(string[] args)      
{         
var contador = 0;       
Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un numero... Para salir presione OK");          
var numero = Console.ReadLine();        
 contador = Convert.ToInt32(numero);        
 while (numero.ToLower() != "ok")         
 {            
  Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un numero... Para salir presione OK");
  numero = Console.ReadLine();           
  contador += Convert.ToInt32(numero);     
 }

 Console.WriteLine("La suma de sus numeros es= "+contador);      
}
```

Comment: No puedes convertir a `Int32` el String "Ok"

Comment: Como dice en la respuesta corta , no se puede convertir el `String` **OK**  a `int` obtendrás fácil una `numberFormatException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No logro entender que es lo que trata de hacer en general. Pero respondiendo su pregunta puntual creo que yo lo manejaría así:
Lo que ingresen por teclado debería ser de tipo string, buscaría la cadena que da la salida y si no corresponde confirmaría si se trata de un numero y para esto 
Utilizaría la función int.TryParse(). Le dejo este código a ver si  le ayuda.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int contador = 0;
        int sumaNumeros = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un numero... O escriba OK para salir");
        string entradaTeclado = Console.ReadLine();

        while (entradaTeclado.ToLower() != "ok")
        {
            // Si lo escrito por teclado es un numero lo guarda en esta variable
            int NumeroIngresado;
            // Verifica si el numero ingresado es numerico
            bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(entradaTeclado, out NumeroIngresado);

            if (isNumeric == true)
            {
                sumaNumeros = NumeroIngresado + contador;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("La suma de sus numeros es= " + sumaNumeros);
            entradaTeclado = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Estimado! Muchisimas gracias por su respuesta! Es todo lo que necesitaba!
Gracias :)